# Go to specific point in image on a picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

Is this possible?

I want to do something like store the X and Y coordinates of a point in an image and jump to that area on the click of a button.

What I have in my form is a `Panel` with the `Auto Scroll` property set to `true`. Inside the panel is a `PictureBox`, if the image gets bigger scroll bars appear on the panel. So what I currently have is getting the positions of the scrollbars then moving to that position using `Panel1.AutoScrollPosition` works fine except if the image size changes like when zooming in or out, then i'm looking at the wrong position.

So is it possible to get a specific point on the image itself and not the picturebox or any control in the form? Note that the image i'm currently playing with is 33722 x 4672.

Comment: Hiya - Is your program written in c# or in vb.net - Either way the accepted way to ask questions is to only tag the language you're using. I know it's tempting to add more tags to get a wider audience, but often it can result in a narrower audience for people like me who mark tags to be ignored. For example I ignore c# tags, so normally I wouldn't notice this question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the **Bitmap** class.

You can use the function **GetPixel()** to get the pixel at a location in your image.

To put your PictureBox Image into a Bitmap object do this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(mypicturebox.Image);
bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
```

Comment: I don't think that's it. I just read about that function and says it's used to get the color of the pixel. Then there's another function called `SetPixel()` which sets that color of the pixel. What I need is to find a way to go to that pixel on a big image.

Comment: So you need the index' for a particular pixel.  If you obtain the PictureBox and Mouse position relative to the form, you can find which pixel your mouse is hovering over by taking the difference.  This would work given the proper scaling.
If your Image scale is zoomable, you'd need to keep track of that to.